# Modify variable in struct from different thread

Tags: c, multithreading

I have two threads.
One is creating struct and filling it with data:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
struct arg_struct args;
args.remoteSockfd = remoteSockfd;
/*...*/
args.active = 1;
```

then I add it into array:

```
while(activeSockets[index].active!=0){
              index++;
          }
activeSockets[index] = args;
```

and creating new thread:

```
(void) pthread_create(&serverThread, NULL, threadBody, &args);
}
```

In second thread I have:

```
void *threadBody(void *args) {
/*...*/
arg_struct *foo = (arg_struct*) (args);
}
```

So now I can access variables in structure:

```
sockfd = foo->remoteSockfd;
```

but when I try to modify them:

```
  foo->active=0;
```

it do not change variable in first thread. How can I modify struct in first thread from another thread?

Comment: This is gonna need WHOLE part of your code, not just some parts.

Comment: If there isn't an error somewhere else...did you try to simply declare `active` as `volatile`?

Comment: I think you need to read a textbook on multithreading, in particular locking and cross-thread memory consistency.  (Disregard this comment if your reaction to https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/memory-barriers.txt is "yeah, yeah, I know all this".)

Comment: Patching variables between threads without proper synchronization is an absolute no go. It might seem the easy way out, but if you don't know exactly what you're doing it will all end in tears. Your time would be best spent learning about parallel processes synchronization than trying to fix a conceptually broken code.

Comment: I think I can do this without synchronization since there is only one thread which "can" change that variable and then ends and only one thread which reads it (of course you couldn't know this). Tears there are caused only by lack of my knowledge of C and english. Also volatile has no effect. It creates warning: `passing argument 4 of ‘pthread_create’ discards ‘volatile’ qualifier from pointer target type`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your problem is here:

```
activeSockets[index] = args;
```

This is copying the data in the structure and not a pointer to it. If you modify args, in another thread or not, then the data in activeSockets will not be changed.  You need to either make activeSockets an array of pointers, not structs, or pass &activeSockets[i] to the other thread.

That's my guess anyway.

Comment: Thank you, but how can I do that? I have edited code:
`arg_struct *activeSockets[25];
activeSockets[index] = &args;`
but now I have segmentation fault (it runs okay only for first time).

Comment: You have to allocate space for the structure. Otherwise you are just using the same structure over again with different pointers.  Try it the other way: pass a pointer to the array element instead of args.